# How would blockchain mining work for non-cryptocurrency applications?

Tags: blockchain

I am new to blockchain. I have read several articles and tutorials, and I get the idea, but there is one thing I still don't understand: mining.

My understanding is that, for blockchain to be truly decentralized, the ledger has to be maintained by a sufficiently large number of miners. For cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, miners are rewarded with Bitcoins, and so they are motivated to do it.

But in other types of applications, why would anyone have motivation to mine? I mean you can't just "store data in a blockchain". You must be able to guarantee the existence of a number of miners who are willing to store this data and maintain the ledger. The application's business model must include a motivation for mining.

Is my understanding correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The term "mining" generally applies to proof of work blockchain systems, where a decentralised group of nodes attempt to solve the proof of work problem for a given difficulty. This process is computationally intensive and results in tangible financial costs to the miner. The reward for successfully mining a block acts as an incentive to participate in the securing of the network despite the financial cost. The primary role of miners is to publish transactions to the distributed ledger.

Proof of work is not the only method to be used for securing a blockchain network, and while mining as described here does not happen in other consensus models, there are still rewards for participating in the network. Some examples of incentivisation regimes include ["Master Nodes" used in Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash_(cryptocurrency)#Masternodes). By staking a large number of tokens and running a master node, participants gain the right to participate in the governance process.

See [this article](https://blockonomi.com/proof-of-stake-coins/) for more examples of proof of stake rewards, and ways that projects incentivise participation in the network.